# Dynamic images In JasperReports (sqlite)

Tags: java, sqlite, jasper-reports

I have tried various different ways which i read from other questions but none of them seem working for me ...

I am using NetBeans 7.4 as front-end and Sqlite as Backend , iReport 5.5

I am making college ic-ards in which i want photo to be fetched from database ,In Database images are stored as blob , i am storing them as bytes..

My Requirement is getting student images from Database for ICard So i can print them..

Below is code i am using to insert image into Database

```
File image= new File(logPath2);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(image);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
for(int readNum;(readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1; ) {
  bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
}
person_image=bos.toByteArray();
```

I have already tried various image expressions and class expressions, but none seem working ..

Please note i am talking about sqlite, i know ways to do it by mysql but sqlite, its not rendering. But i don't wanna shift from sqlite to mysql.

Error i get is

```
Error filling print... Unable to get value for field 'Photo' of class 'java.io.I‌​nputStream' net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'Photo' o‌​f class 'java.io.InputStream' at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource.getFieldValue(JRResultS‌​etDataSource.java:319) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset‌​.java:1356) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:12‌​57) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:12‌​33) –
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what isn't working. Just telling us that something doesn't work is going to get this question closed down before very long...

Comment: Error is in rendering image from database

Comment: But what is the error?

Comment: Error filling print... Unable to get value for field 'Photo' of class 'java.io.InputStream' 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'Photo' of class 'java.io.InputStream'      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource.getFieldValue(JRResultSetDataSource.java:319)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1356)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1257)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1233)

Comment: You should include that stack trace in the question. You should also show the code, where the error is occurring. The code you have currently shown does not attempt to read a field called `Photo` from a database table, so it doesn't appear to be in any way related to the issue you are having.